# Sort DataTable - show selected rows first

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am using the table-plugin for jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to display a HTML-Table. In addition I am using the [Select-Plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/simple.html)  which allows to (multi)select table rows. As a user select a row, the class "`selected`" is added to the `<tr>` element:

```
<tr id="tr_1" class="odd selected">
```

How can I sort the rows, that the selected rows are shown first? This would improve clarity, especially with many rows or pages provided by DataTable.